# List.OrderBy define order in a variable

Tags: c#, list

I have a list containing objects  :

```
class MyType
{
    String Name;
    String Address;
    DateTime BirthDay;
}

List<MyType> myList;
```

I want to write a function working like this :

```
public void SortList(int value)
{
    // orderValue => this is the variable I need
    if (value == 0)
        orderValue = MyType.Name; // Sort list by Name
    else if (value == 1)
        orderValue = MyType.Address; // Sort list by Address
    else if (value == 1)
        orderValue = MyType.BirthDay; // Sort list by BirthDay

    if (orderValue != null)
    {
        List<MyType> sortedList = myList.OrderBy(orderValue).ToList();
        if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(myList, sortedList))
            sortedList = myList.OrderByDescending(orderValue).ToList();
        myList = sortedList;
    }
}
```

How can I write my `orderValue` to make this code working ?

This is just a synthesis of my code, I can provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OrderBy can accept Func and you can have variable like this

```
Func<Person, string> orderFunc = x => x.Name;

if (value == 0)
   orderFunc = x => x.Name;
else if (value == 1)
   orderFunc = x => x.Address;

myList = myList.OrderBy(orderFunc).ToList();
```

Comment: I initialized orderFunc with null value and your code is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Note that all attributes must be of the same type in order to use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways of doing it. For example, you can add `OrderBy` clause inside your conditional statement, like this:

```
IEnumerable<MyType> data = myList;
if (value == 0)
    data = data.OrderBy(x => x.Name); // Sort list by Name
else if (value == 1)
    data = data.OrderBy(x => x.Address); // Sort list by Address
res = data.ToList();
```

You can also do it in a single statement:

```
res = myList
    .OrderBy(x => value == 0 ? x.Name : "")
    .ThenBy(x => value == 1 ? x.Address : "")
    .ToList();
```

This is somewhat harder to read, but it will do the work on RDBMS side in EF or LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
myList.OrderBy((x) => (value == 0 ? x.Name : x.Address));
```